# Does the gentile seeking conversion have more obligations than a Noahide Person?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, noachide-laws

I am a gentile seeking to convert to Judaism, but I can't make a contact with a Beit Din since there is no Rabbi in my country neither an active Synagogue. But I am very serious toward conversion and being Noahide is too basic for me. I will convert in the far future after relocating outside the country.

Since I am seeking conversion, do I have more obligation than a Noahide ?

Comment: Also, instead of focusing on what you think should be doing, focus on the community around you and if they're keeping and teaching the sheva mitzvot to others. Establish a community of your own. What if a Rabbi doesn't come? What if you can never be officially accepted/mekablin by a beit din? Instead of moving to where you think it is better to convert, make your world there more pure and holy.

Comment: @EhevuTov you mean like establishing a Noahide community in my area ? (of course with the supervising of a Rabbi)

Comment: @mil, yes, establish a community in your area. You do not need a supervising Rabbi(it's a ben Noach community and learned bnei Noach are all that is needed) although one is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only obligated to keep the seven mitzvot bnei Noach/seven laws of the children of Noah. If you desire, you may do more: you do them properly(Hilchot Melachim 10:10, Raavad on Hilchot Issurei Bi'ah 14:7-8, Avodah Zara 64b, Krisos 9a).

You are only obligated to do more mitzvot than the seven if you take upon yourself the whole Torah. There may be a significance if you do a mitzvah three times that you then have to keep that mitzvah, but I'm unsure if that applies.

Comment: for example: If I recited modeh ani 3 days in a row, I will have to keep this mitzvah ?

Comment: @mil, yes that would be an example, but I'm not sure if that applies to you.

Comment: @mil: The best way to avoid having to keep anything extra is to think beforehand that you are not doing the practice as an obligation. It is better to think this before any practice, but I believe it works if that is your overall intent when it comes to these matters.

Comment: That's an interesting point about the 3 times thing. I wonder if it applies to mitzvoth that Rabbis dispute whether a non-Jew can keep in the first place(like mezuzah, tzitzit, and tefillin).

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom precisely. I was at Dr. Vendyl Jones' home over the weekend. He is a famous non-Jew/ben Noach. He had mezuzot. I was perplexed by this so I did some searching on the matter. I found a video where Vendyl said he kept mezuzot because he did them at least 3 times when he lived in Israel. I'm not sure if it pertains to non-Jews or not. I want to say, but am very hesitant to say, that this does apply to gerim and is the actual personal acceptance(not mekablin beit din, but a personal acceptance of a mitzvah) practice for the ger.

Comment: @EhevuTov: Interesting. I am not sure what you are trying to say in your last few sentences, though.

Comment: In other words, the only type of ger that is accepted by the Jewish community outside of Yovel is a ger tzedek. However, a ger toshav does exist today and it seems he can do mitzvot, but not because he is commanded. How does he do them then? It seems maybe he takes them on one at a time as he understands them and if he does one enough times he should keep that one.

Comment: @mil: As for any practices you did 3 times without explicit intent to not do it permanently, but you want to discontinue them , I would suggest you do an "annulment of oaths." There are standard texts in some prayer books (especially the ones used during the 10 days of awe--Rosh Hashana and yom Kippur), but you do not need to use a standard text. You should stand before 1 person who is at least 13 years old and state that you regret the fact that you created an obligation for the stated religious practice(s) (you should state what they were if you remember them)...

Comment: @mil: …you may have done and you declare the obligation null and void. The person then says "it is permitted for you" and you then not obligated to do those practices (assuming you are actually obligated in the first place, which is unclear to me, but I wrote this just to help clear the issue from your conscience in case you feel guilty for not keeping those practices anymore or in case you may not want to do them indefinitely). The Divine Code (by Rabbi Moshe Weiner) says that a Gentile does not need 3 Jews to annul oaths like Jews usually do and can use any person (Jew or Gentile).

Comment: @EhevuTov You may want to edit your comment to include the prohibition of learning Torah and keeping Shabbos per Melachim 10:9.

Comment: @Y K Bnei Noach have no such prohibition that the goy does concerning Shabbos and involvement in Torah. Goy and Bnei Noach are in two different gederim.

Answer (score 15):

God expects Jews to follow the torah and gentiles to follow the Noachide laws.  Until you've converted you're still a gentile and don't have additional heavenly obligations.

Perhaps you have heard of people in the process of conversion being required to do more.  If so, it's likely a misunderstanding.  Once you are studying with a rabbi he will guide you to take on more *mitzvot* in advance of conversion -- but that's not because you're obligated yet; it's because you need to learn to pray, keep kosher, keep Shabbat, and so on.  In the same way, we teach children below the age of bar or bat mitzvah to do these things, not because they're (yet) obligated but because they will be and need to prepare.  The instant you complete your conversion you'll be Jewish and fully obligated to the whole torah; that would be a bad time to start learning how to do it.